# Can't override post type using custom Elementor query

Tags: wp-query

I need to use Posts element to display posts from two post types. Since I have to select a source, I've selected Post, but then my custom query can't override this.

Following the first example from these instructions https://developers.elementor.com/docs/hooks/custom-query-filter/, I've added this code to functions.php, but with no effect. When I override posts_per_page or something else, that works, but 'post-type' does not.

[image]

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/latest-posts-home', function ( $query ) {
    $query->set('post-type', array('alicorn_case_studies', 'post'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing a small typo should be it (untested):

```php
add_action( 'elementor/query/latest-posts-home', function ( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'alicorn_case_studies', 'post' ) );
} );
```

The parameter `post-type` should be `post_type`.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked this this.